# Allow arbitrary loads set to YES, but request still fails?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I'm running into a problem I haven't seen before on my iOS app.

I'm on device, iOS 13.2.3.

When running a normal download task:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (tmpFileURL, response, error) in ...  }
task.resume()
```

It errors out:

```
Task <1714E406-8728-48C3-AB12-ED353A618B52>.<1> finished with error [-1202] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid
```

The interesting thing is that the resource I am downloading "mp4", is on S3, and on my FTP client on my Mac I can access the resource fine using "http://" and also "https://".

So, first thing I check is to make sure I have this in my info.plist:

[image]

So, I am not sure why the app is unable to download the mp4 given the arbitrary load setting and given the fact on a normal FTP client I can access the resource fine. Arbitrary loads set to YES should bypass the need of the certificate.

Any idea?

Comment: Try clean, build or restart your Xcode once.

Comment: didn't help. Still won't work.

Comment: Have you deleted DerivedData folder?

Comment: yes. Deleting derived data did not work.

Comment: The error suggests that even though arbitrary loads is enabled, the tmpFileURL is actually a https URL, therefore it will try to use https anyway and fail because the certificate is not valid. change the scheme to http and try it again and it should work.

Comment: You may need to add the domain you are connecting to, to the [NSExceptionDomains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsexceptiondomains). [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity)